# Finding Inverse of a 4*4 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the inverse of the following matrix
$$
\begin{array}{c}
{\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
c_{0} & c_{1} & c_{2} & c_{3} \\
c_{2} & c_{3} & c_{0} & c_{1} \\
c_{3} & -c_{2} & c_{1} & -c_{0} \\
c_{1} & -c_{0} & c_{3} & -c_{2}
\end{array}\right]} \\
\text { where } c_{0}=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{4 \sqrt{2}}, c_{1}=\frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{4 \sqrt{2}}, c_{2}=\frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{4 \sqrt{2}} \text { and } c_{3}=\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{4 \sqrt{2}}
\end{array}
$$

I had thought of replacing the values with trigonometric values like Sin 15 , cos 15 .... But it seems very lengthy. Any shorter approach?

Comment: The idea of replacing the values with $\sin(\pi/12), \cos(\pi/12), \dots$ seems like an interesting idea for the computation, since then the determinant will have terms like $\sin(\pi/12)\cos(\pi/12) = \frac{1}{2}\sin(\pi/6)$ (using the double angle formula). In terms of calculating the inverse, you can try Cramers rule, but I don't think there is going to be a particularly 'pretty' way, i.e. having much shorter computation.

Comment: Just in case it inspires anyone to find an elegant solution, the determinant in terms of the $c_i$'s is $[(c_0-c_2)^2+(c_1-c_3)^2][(c_0+c_2)^2+(c_1+c_3)^2]$.

Comment: how can u reach this elegent solution?

Comment: All I did was plug the matrix into WolframAlpha. I don't know for sure if there is an elegant solution. However, in a lot of problems, knowing the answer ahead of time can make it easier to find a solution. Hence why I provided it in that comment.

Comment: okay,thanks indeed

Comment: Hint: It seem that the columns are pairwise orthogonal to each other.

Comment: can u explain clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns are pairwise orthogonal to each other.

So, with

$$A=
{\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
c_{0} & c_{1} & c_{2} & c_{3} \\
c_{2} & c_{3} & c_{0} & c_{1} \\
c_{3} & -c_{2} & c_{1} & -c_{0} \\
c_{1} & -c_{0} & c_{3} & -c_{2}
\end{array}\right]} \\
$$

You have

$$A^TA = qI_{4\times 4} \text{ with } q= \sum_{k=0}^3c_k^2 =1$$

Hence,

$$A^{-1} = A^T$$

So, the columns of matrix $A$ form an orthonormal basis.

Comment: thanks! it is indeed a great solution!

Comment: You are welcome :-). Thank you for your appreciation.

Comment: I am getting  A*A^T = underroot(3/4)*I ..am i doing wrong>

Comment: The main diagonal has everywhere the value $ \sum_{k=0}^3c_k^2$. When calculating this you need to be very careful because of the many root expressions. It is easy to make a mistake while calculating this sum of squares.

Comment: i am substitute with trigonomtric values , so it's not hard

Comment: Here I copied it into WA:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%5Cfrac%7B1%2B%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%7B4+%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D%29%5E2%2B%28%5Cfrac%7B3%2B%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%7B4+%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D%29%5E2%2B%28%5Cfrac%7B3-%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%7B4+%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D%29%5E2+%2B%28%5Cfrac%7B1-%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%7B4+%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D%29%5E2

Comment: yeah! i have also got that ,those 4 square root values will be equal to 1....

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: Your $c_3$ has the wrong sign. You have $c_3 = -\frac 12 \sin(15°)$

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer as it the MathJax for the matrix will not fit in a comment. Mathematica gives a rather nasty expression for the inverse of the matrix:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{1}{560} \left(8 \sqrt{6}-29\right) & \frac{1}{560} \left(99-8 \sqrt{6}\right) & \frac{1}{560} \left(-8 \sqrt{6}-29\right) & \frac{1}{560} \left(8 \sqrt{6}+99\right) \\
 \frac{1}{560} \left(8 \sqrt{6}+99\right) & \frac{1}{560} \left(-8 \sqrt{6}-29\right) & \frac{1}{560} \left(8 \sqrt{6}-99\right) & \frac{1}{560} \left(29-8 \sqrt{6}\right) \\
 \frac{1}{560} \left(99-8 \sqrt{6}\right) & \frac{1}{560} \left(8 \sqrt{6}-29\right) & \frac{1}{560} \left(8 \sqrt{6}+99\right) & \frac{1}{560} \left(-8 \sqrt{6}-29\right) \\
 \frac{1}{560} \left(-8 \sqrt{6}-29\right) & \frac{1}{560} \left(8 \sqrt{6}+99\right) & \frac{1}{560} \left(29-8 \sqrt{6}\right) & \frac{1}{560} \left(8 \sqrt{6}-99\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Showing this result analytically seems a daunting task.